# Access from design wrapper to variables of own IP block in Vivado (verilog)

Tags: verilog, vivado

I have a question. I created a block diagram in Vivado2018.2. One of the blocks is an own created IP block. I want access to a variable of this own IP block in my design wrapper to test something. My design wrapper looks like:

```
`timescale 1 ps / 1 ps

module design_1_wrapper
   ();



design_1 design_1_i
   ();


endmodule
```

I would like to add LD0 - LD7 in the outputs, that's not an issue. 
But something like

```
assign LD0 = design_1.
```

or

```
assign LD0 = design_1_i.
```

followed by name of my block and internal modules in a pointwise way dos=esn't work because he twice mentions that he doesn't recognize design_1 or design_1_i. Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in the block diagram of vivado make the desired ports as output ports, such that ur new design wrapper will look like

```
    `timescale 1 ps / 1 ps

module design_1_wrapper
   ();



design_1 design_1_i
 (......
  ,.LED       (LED(7:0))
);


endmodule
```